# Update values in every sub-document in an array

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I need to store a user's preference for the display order of a number of screen items, but I don't know how to record this easily.

I have this collection in mongodb

```json
{
    "userId": "1",
    "applications":[
        {
            "appName": "Vacation System",
            "appUrl":"http://localhost:8080/app",
            "appIcon":"https://lh3.ggpht.com/HlefFaVW39Vbv1q5pm1bOxX7FcOuZDWv0TH1reLUFxhXTi-Eah0CEJvS5Mv3DYRv8mk=w300",
            "key":1,
            "sort":1
        },
        {
            "appName": "inventory System",
            "appUrl":"http://localhost:8080/app",
            "appIcon":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aMoTzec746RIY9GFOKMjipqBShsKos_KxeDtS59tRp4-ePCpGqW2bS-ySyUEL6q3gkA=w300",
            "key":2,
            "sort":2
        },
        {
            "appName": "HR System",
            "appUrl":"http://localhost:8080/app",
            "appIcon":"https://www.sleepio.com/img/logos/sleepio-s-logo-full.png",
            "key":3,
            "sort":3
        }
    ]
}
```

I use this data to render a grid view such that the user can drag each view, change its position, and sort it as they like; but with each move I have to change the sort value of each view, which is in the applications array in each sub-document.

I was thinking about making a new obj and change this collection by the new obj but don't know how to do that.

Or I was also thinking of making an array of the sorted values, `[3, 2, 1]`, and updating the sort value of each sub-document in the applications array in the existing collection, but again I don't know how.

Comment: Hi scully, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I tweaked your question to clarify the wording where I could, but there's one point where I was stuck: what do you mean by "_I was thinking about making a new obj and change this collection by the new obj but don't know how to do that._" ? Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your questions to make them as clear and useful as possible.

Comment: i meant i was thinking about making a new collection and replace the old one